# Computing fractions within a "for each" set (Tikz Picture)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to specify polar angles in radians rather than degrees, but I'm unable to input fractions as an argument for the angle. The following code

```
\foreach \x  in {0 , pi/6, 7*pi/6 }
  \draw (1.0027*\x r : 0.1*\x) circle (2pt) node[above] {a};
```

draws a 2pt circle at the specified location for x=0 but fails to produce anything for x=pi/6 or 7*pi/6. I'd eventually like to include text specific to x at each node, so that I'd have something like

```
\foreach \x/\xtext  in {0/firsttext , pi/6 /secondtext, 7*pi/6 /thirdtext}
  \draw (1.0027*\x r : 0.1*\x) circle (2pt) node[above] {\xtext};
```

but the front slash is now ambiguous: even if it were to properly function as the division operator how could it be distinguished from a seperator?

So I'm wondering if there's another way to tell the compiler to compute fractions?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an extra pair of braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\foreach \x/\xtext  in {0/texta,{pi/6}/textb,{7*pi/6}/textc}
  \draw (1.0027*\x r : 0.1*\x) circle (2pt) node[above] {\xtext};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```